# Refresh the entire Lightning Page based on events

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a custom lightning page which has two lightning components and 2 visualforce pages. In the lightning components whenever any changes being done I have used the force:refreshview event getting fired so that the new value can be seen on the screen. Even though the refreshview event fired but I don't see the VF getting loaded again with the new values. It still contain the old one which was there at the time of loading the page.

Any idea why ? is their any way to refresh the entire lightning page (though it will be slow) but I open to other ideas if any?

Comment: You can try window.location.reload

Comment: VF pages are inside lightning component? Or components inside another vf page (lightning.out)?

Comment: VF pages are not inside lightning component. its a standalone VF page in the lightning page.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty: I had tried location reload, parent.location.reload. window.location.href, it didn worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the easiest way to achieve this is instead of refreshing the view just simply redirecting to the same page. My helper method:

```
    gotoURL : function (component, event, helper, url, isRedirect) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": url,
      "isredirect": isRedirect
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
},
```

Unlike refreshView this will refresh VF inside. With new URL format you can just pass it like /mypage

Comment: I will try this